# How to get values instead of Key from Choices when you use objects.filter(id=pk).values() on Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-filter

Is it possible to get the Choice VALUE instead of KEY, when you use Django `model.objects.filter()`

In my case, I have

`models.py`

```
BIN_TYPE=(
    ('BLUE', 'Blue'),
    ('BROW', 'Brown'),
    ('GREY','Grey'),
    ('OTHER','Other')
    )



class BinCollection(models.Model):
    bin_type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=BIN_TYPE)
```

`views.py`

`bin_collections':BinCollection.objects.filter(id=pk).values('bin_type')`

From HTML side, I can use `obj.get_bin_type_display()` . However, I need this data on views for further calculations.

If I was using a table, `bin_type__values` would work but not for choice. Any ideas?

Comment: Then you normally use  `ForeignKey`, not a `CharField`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Thank you, can you use `ForeignKey` for Choices or are you suggesting to move the values to a new table? Initially, I thought about to keep the values in a table but these values won't change that much.